# PdkMake- Align Table to Right and Content not displaying inside Table

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, pdfmake

I was using pdkmake in a project and i came around some issues with table alignment and dividing a row into col's but 2nd col values doesn't display! , also unable to view dividing line .

I tried using this as a reference : http://pdfmake.org/playground.html tables tab is in 6th option . but nothing worked out for me :/

can anyone help me with this ? I am trying to display something like this :
[image]

but my view of table is something like this :
[image]

The small table needs to be left aligned with all contents displayed as it is.

Here are all the details i have for my current PDF Data with styles :
i have a full page border, with all details display as i need. Only issue is this inner table is what i am strugging with !

```
<button className="btn btn-md btn-primary mt-0 nowrap" onClick={onGeneratePDF}>
  DOWNLOAD INVOICE
</button>

 const onGeneratePDF = async () => {
  const pdf = await generateInvoicePDF(data);

  const docDefinition = {
    content: pdf.content,
    defaultStyle: {
      font: 'Helvetica',
    },
    styles: pdf.styles,
  };

  pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
};



const generateInvoicePDF = async (data: any) => {

    const pdf = {
        content: [
            {
                layout: {
                    hLineColor: 'black',
                    vLineColor: 'black',
                    hLineWidth: () => 1,
                    vLineWidth: () => 1,
                    paddingTop: () => 7,
                    paddingBottom: () => 7,
                },
                table: {
                    widths: ['*'],
                    body: [
                        [
                            {
                                border: [true, true, true, true], // Enable border for all sides
                                stack: [
                                    {
                                        text: `date   4/7/2023`,
                                        style: ['h3', 'right'],
                                        margin: [0, 0, 5, 15],
                                    },
                                    {
                                        text: 'invoice',
                                        style: ['h1', 'center', 'bold'],
                                        margin: [0, 0, 5, 15],
                                    },
                                    {
                                        text : 'dear user',
                                        style:['h3','left'],
                                        margin: [15,0,0,15]

                                    },
                                    {
                                        text : 'date',
                                        style:['h3','left'],
                                        margin: [60,0,0,15]

                                    },
                                    {
                                        // Small Box placement
                                        style:'table1',
                                        table: {
                                            widths: ['40%', '60%'],
                                            heights: [20, 50, 20, 20],
                                            body: [
                                                [
                                                    {
                                                        text: 'name',
                                                        style: ['h2', 'center'],
                                                        // colSpan: 2
                                                    },
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                    {},
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                    {
                                                        text: 'register number',
                                                        style: ['h2', 'center'],
                                                        //  colSpan: 2,
                                                    },   
                                                    {
                                                        text: 'need to display',
                                                        style: ['h2', 'center'],
                                                        //  colSpan: 4,
                                                    }                                              
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                    {
                                                        text: 'ph no',
                                                        style: ['h2', 'center'],
                                                        // colSpan: 2,
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        text: 'need to display',
                                                        style: ['h2', 'center'],
                                                        //  colSpan: 4,
                                                    }  
                                                ]
                                            ],
                                        },
                                        layout: {
                                            hLineColor: 'black', // Set the color of the dividing line
                                            hLineWidth: () => 1, // Set the width of the dividing line
                                            paddingTop: () => 0,
                                            paddingBottom: () => 0,
                                            paddingLeft: () => 0,
                                            paddingRight: () => 0,
                                        },
                                    },
                                    
                                    {
                                        text: 'company name',
                                        style: ['h2', 'center'],
                                    },
                                    {
                                        text:  'xyz company',
                                        style: ['h3', 'center'],
                                        margin: [-5, 0, -10, 15],
                                    },
                                    {
                                        text: 'register num',
                                        style: ['h2', 'center'],
                                    },
                                    {
                                        text: '234324',
                                        style: ['h3', 'center'],
                                        margin: [-5, 0, -10, 16],
                                    },
                                    {
                                        text: 'license',
                                        style: ['h2', 'center'],
                                    },
                                    {
                                        text:  '45645',
                                        style: ['h3', 'center'],
                                        margin: [-5, 0, -10, 16],
                                    },
                                ],
                            },
                        ],
                    ],
                },
            },
        ],
        styles: {
            h1: {
                fontSize: 16,
            },
            h2: {
                fontSize: 12,
            },
            h3: {
                fontSize: 10,
            },
            center: {
                alignment: 'center',
            },
            'border-bottom': {
                decoration: 'underline',
                decorationColor: 'black',
                decorationStyle: 'solid',
                decorationLineWidth: 1,
            },
            right: {
                alignment: 'right',
            },
            left : {
                alignment : 'left',
            },
            bold: {
                bold: true,
            },
            'table1':{
                alignment : 'right !important',
            }
        },
    };

    return pdf;
};
```

It's all the required code , Still finding a solution for this , any help is much appreciated !
thank you !